# "A group that X" or "A group who X"? (American English)

Tags: pronouns

I've been asked to proofread a company newsletter, and I came across this line:

> [Department name] is something special – an elite unit **who** finds
> opportunities where others cannot.

Should it rather be "an elite group **that** finds opportunities where others cannot"?

It seems to me that the relative pronoun for a "unit" would be "that" rather than "who" even if the unit/department is made up of people. Am I correct?

Comment: I like your thinking. Or add "an elite unit **whose staff** finds opportunities."

Comment: Using _that_ solves all these problems, and others, like singular/plural agreement.

Comment: Your question does not contain enough information for me to offer a helpful answer.  Is the idea to praise a specific unit for ITS united achievement, of is it intended as praise for the individual members, albeit expressed collectively.  The decision between singular and plural depends on your answer to that.

Comment: @Tuffy, the point is to praise the department as a whole, I suppose. The Sales Department, let's say, has done a great job finding opportunities. This is in the introduction of the article.

Later on in the text, the author does narrow things down and speak about being part of this unit. They go on to say "Being a part of this group means we face challenges that others do not."

Does that make a difference?

Comment: In that case, would you say it is being praised as a high performing individual or as separate high performing individuals?

Comment: @Tuffy I'd say the department itself is being praised as a high-performing, individual department within the company.

Comment: @AranYarne Then you have answered your own question:  singular should be used.  But the job of editor surely includes checking with the author as to what they intended.